# iOS 7.1 app is crashing in showing alert view

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uialertview

I have used alertview many times but currently i have an issue. My app is working in all the version except it is crashing in iOS 7.1. Below is the log message.

```
[_UIBarBackgroundCustomImageContainer image]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x13b88840

 UIAlertView *alert  =   [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" @"Test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 [alert show];
```

I don't understand why it is only crashing in iOS 7.1

Comment: post code of show your alertview .

Comment: Post Your alertview Code .......

Comment: @"TestTitle" @"Test" Title is Wrong replace it @"TestTitle Test"

Comment: @KiritModi- what will change if i change the string... nothing.. the app crashes whatever i put in title.. and it's working in iOS 7.0 and lower

Comment: `[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TestTitle" @"Test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:kActionOk otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];` this line has many issues replace with `[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TestTitle" message:@"Test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:kActionOk otherButtonTitles:nil];` And this shouldn't work in any iOS at all, why you may ask. Because the method ` initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` doesn't exist it should be  `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`

Comment: @Popeye- can u write your comment in answer

Comment: @John done as requested

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to be on main thread ?

You can test it like this : `[NSThread isMainThread];`

Comment: Dont use SELF just use NIL  while setting delegate of UIAlertView :  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your message!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; We should use self in delegate when we are working on alertview delegate to track which buttonindex is pressed .

Answer (score 0):

As requested by the OP I have just moved my comments to be an answer.

There are a few issues wrong with the following line:

```
[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TestTitle" @"Test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:kActionOk otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

just replace it with

```
[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TestTitle" message:@"Test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

As for what the issues are with that line, they are:

1) The method `initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` isn't a real instance method for `UIAlertView` so it shouldn't work in any `iOS` where as you have said it does work in `iOS` versions prior to 7. The method that you should be using is `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` notice the extra parameter `message:` this is the main issue and should create a compiler error and if it got passed that should throw a runtime error of `unrecognised selector`.

2) The second is is that you have two `nil`s being passed in for the last parameter for `otherButtonTitle:`, this parameter is `nil` terminated so as soon as it sees `nil` it will end what can be passed into that parameter so the second `nil` is pointless and never seen. This also may create a compiler error but would be in the shadows of the first issue (1)

For more information in regards to `UIAlertView` please the [Apple Documentation on `UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)